# do you need app_id for dialog.feed

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed, share

I have a simple site with a playlist-driven flash movie player.

the site is NOT a facebook app.

when a user clicks a video to watch from the playlist, that video's title, description, and thumbnail are registered in javascript variables.

the site also has a facebook button for sharing. If the user hits the fb share button while video_123 is playing then the video_123-info should show up when the share posts to the user's fb wall.

the only problem is that the http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed seems to require a app_id, but my site is not a fb app.

any suggestions please?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have application to use Dialogs.

Just create an application configure it pointing to your site (without configuring application canvas) and use [`Feed Dialog`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

**Update:**
If you must not create application for any reasons the only option for you is to use [`Facebook Share` button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) (which is deprecated) see "Creating Your Own Share URL" section...

**Update 2:**
Share button is deprecated and it's documentation is no longer available (link above redirects to documentation of `Feed Dialog`, [old page on web-archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20101205120615/http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share))

Comment: juicy scripter, thanks for responding. The problem is that the site is for a client who does not have a facebook account, and does not want to set up one (they are a government institution).

and I really don't like the idea of me creating an 'app' using my facebook account that refers to their website.

I am using feed.dialog because it allows dynamic population of the share content fields ... is there any other way to do this possibly?